# Can't use '$' symbol to output properties and I seem to get an output of 0 if I output only 1

Tags: c#

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Car car = new Car(999, "g", BrandType.Lada);
        car.Introduce();
    }
}
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public BrandType Brand { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Car(decimal Price, string Model, BrandType brand)
    {
    }

    public void Introduce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.Brand}-{this.Price}-{this.Model}");
    }

}
```

}

Can't use '$' symbol to output properties and I seem to get an output of 0 if I output only 1 and I don't know why. My BrandType consists of 4 brands. If I output this.Brand I get 0 and so with this.Price and this.Mode.

Comment: do you just want a $ at the beginning of the string?

Comment: What do you think using `$` will do?

Comment: `$` requires C# 6.0

Comment: I want to output the properties of my object,but it seems I can't use '$' because of my c# version...